# Undefined error continues showing shorthand if statement

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a shorthand if statement because I want to display an empty property if my variable is undefined. The problem is that I keep getting an error about the obj displaying not being able to read the property. The error i am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" Any suggestions?

```
    var actions = {
    success : function (data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        //the problem starts here
        chart_data = obj.series.data.series != 'undefined' ? (obj.series.data.series.data) : '';

        chart_name['series'] = [{
            name: obj.series.name,
            data: chart_data
        }];

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_name);
        //------------------------------------------------------
        // Set titles for charts
        //------------------------------------------------------
        chart.setTitle({text: obj.title});

        //------------------------------------------------------
        // Set sub titles for charts
        //------------------------------------------------------
        chart.setTitle(null, {text: ' '});
    }
};
```

repsonse from data

```
Success: {"comparison":false,"title":"Projects by Area Breakdown | January 2016 to July 2015","series":{"name":"Area Breakdown","colorByPoint":true,"data":""}}
```

Comment: `obj.series` is undefined, so you'll not be able to `obj.series.data`. Simple.

Comment: your error mean "obj.series" is undefined, check in console log value of "obj"

Comment: no no, obj.series.data.series is undefined which it is suppose to be. The error is coming from obj.series.data.series.data

Answer (score 0):

This is the response you got:

```js
{
  "comparison": false,
  "title": "Projects by Area Breakdown | January 2016 to July 2015",
  "series": {
    "name": "Area Breakdown",
    "colorByPoint": true,
    "data": ""
  }
}
```

And you are trying:

```
chart_data = obj.series.data.series
```

As you can see there is no `series` in the `"data":""`. so that causes in a js error.

---

My suggestion is to check for length of it:

```
chart_data = obj.series.data.length !== 0  ? obj.series.data : "";
```

or a shorter one:

```
chart_data = obj.series.data || "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

*Assuming the check for `undefined` means that sometimes `obj.series.data` has a valid `series` property and sometimes not.*

---

```
obj.series.data.series != 'undefined'
```

should be

```
obj.series.data.series != undefined
```

Notice that `undefined` is not a string `''`.

or a more better way

```
obj.series.data.series !== undefined
```

---

```js
var obj = {
  "comparison": false,
  "title": "Projects by Area Breakdown | January 2016 to July 2015",
  "series": {
    "name": "Area Breakdown",
    "colorByPoint": true,
    "data": ""
  }
}
var chart_data = obj.series.data.series !== undefined ? (obj.series.data.series.data) : '';
console.log('chart_data : ',chart_data)
```

Comment: That's why I answered using typeof but got downvote and you still posting your answer same.. :)

Comment: The `key` data does not have any object with key `series`, so this will break the code there.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, the main issue was the string literal used to compare `undefined`. And I *did not* post the same answer using `typeof`; nor did I downvote.`:)`

Comment: @Jai, *No*, the code *won't break*; that is what the `undefined` check is there for. :). The main reason the asker is doing this is because sometimes `obj.series.data` has a `series` property and sometime it does not.

Comment: @ShaunakD I din't mean that. Just telling you that your and mine answer is same but no helpful to OP.

Comment: @ShaunakD seems okay if you don't have any strict check with `!==` but valid if you have `'undefined' != undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This means that **`obj.series` is undefined.**

A shorthand to avoid this error is to write

```
obj.series = obj.series || {};
```

that initializes it if undefined and put it above the error LOC:

```
function (data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    obj.series = obj.series || {}; 
// ...
```

The issue however is that you access multiple sub-objects at one time, so you have to extend the principle many times:

```
    chart_data = ((obj.series || {}).data || {}).series != 'undefined' ? (((obj.series || {}).data || {}).series || {}).data : '';
```

but that is ugly.

Maybe it is better to pass `obj` to a constructor that initializes the variables you need to `""`.

Secondly the check for undefined variables can be done shortly checking them like:

```
if(obj.series) {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
obj.series ? /* true condition*/ : /* false condition*/
```

or **checking extensively** with:

```
if(typeof obj.series != 'undefined') {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
typeof obj.series != 'undefined' ? /* true condition*/ : /* false condition*/
```